Cannot close a dialog PyQt5
I have the following 2 classes. From UI_mainwindow I open a dialog as seen below. I want that dialog to close when I click on one of those 2 buttons (createProject_btn, openProject_btn). Though nothing seems to be working.
I know this kind of questions have been asked million times, and I'm sure there are duplicates, but my eyes are so new to the python, I cannot follow the patterns. Hence, any help is appreciated.
Note: the ui files are pretty simple, one button on UI_mainwindow to open the dialog, 2 buttons on the dialog to set a property inside and close the dialog.
Ui_mainWindow
import os

from .createOrOpenProjectDialog import CreateOrOpenProjectDialog
from qgis.PyQt import uic
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QDialog)

FORM_CLASS, _ = uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'ui', 'window.ui'))

class Ui_mainWindow(QtWidgets.QDialog, FORM_CLASS):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """Constructor."""
        super(Ui_mainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        # Set up the user interface from Designer through FORM_CLASS.
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.connectSignalsSlots()

    def connectSignalsSlots(self):
        print("main.connectSignalsSlots 1")
        self.pushButton1.clicked.connect(self.createProject)
        print("main.connectSignalsSlots 2")
        
    def createProject(self):
        dialog = MyDialog(self)
        print(dialog.exec())
        dialog.showOutput()

class MyDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        # .dialog is just a handle - class property that we created here
        self.dialog = CreateOrOpenProjectDialog(self)
    
    def showOutput(self):
        print("showOutput:")
        print(self.dialog.clickedButton)

CreateOrOpenProjectDialog
import os

from qgis.PyQt import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QDialog)

# This loads your .ui file so that PyQt can populate your plugin with the elements from Qt Designer
FORM_CLASS, _ = uic.loadUiType(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'ui', 'dialog.ui'))

class CreateOrOpenProjectDialog(QDialog, FORM_CLASS):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """Constructor."""
        super(CreateOrOpenProjectDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(parent)
        self.connectSignalsSlots()

    def connectSignalsSlots(self):
        # todo: figure out if actions are better to use then direct events
        # self.action_create_project.triggered.connect(self.createProject)
        self.createProject_btn.clicked.connect(self.createProject)
        self.openProject_btn.clicked.connect(self.openProject)

    def createProject(self):
        print("dialog.createProject")
        self.clickedButton = "createProj"
        self.accept()
        
    def openProject(self):
        print("dialog.openProject")
        self.clickedButton = "openProj"
        self.accept()



There's really no point in creating the QDialog subclass "MyDialog" containing another QDialog subclass (CreateOrOpenProjectDialog). Either subclass from CreateOrOpenProjectDialog (if you really need to do that) in order to implement the showOutput method, or just implement that in CreateOrOpenProjectDialog and directly create an instance of that class instead. Your code "doesn't work" because you're practically creating a dialog that is a child of another dialog, and you can easily see that by adding self.dialog.show() in the __init__ of MyDialog.

yep, that did the trick. Thank you. I can accept your answer if you post it as an answer.
